# translating hex values from ByteArray in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, arrays, hex

I'm  new to using ByteArray, and am trying to parse hex color values from an .ase (Adobe Swatch Exchange) using ByteArray in AS3. I can see position of the hex values using a hex editor, but don't know which methods to use to parse the hex value from there. Here are the values copied from the hex editor. The 2 color values are #ffffff and #cdcdcd:

ASEF........¿..........$...#.f.f.f.f.f.f..RGB.?Ä..?Ä..?Ä....¿..........$...#.c.d.0.0.c.d..RGB.?MÕŒ....?MÕŒ

I've made a weak initial attempt to get the first color, but am stuck here :

```
    var byteA:ByteArray = _fr.data;
    byteA.position=29;
    var tb:ByteArray = new ByteArray()  
    var tA:Array= new Array(); //temp array
    byteA.readBytes(tb,0,11);
    trace("TB "+ tb[0]+":" +tb.toString())
```

Can somebody please show me how to parse out the color value, so it can be added to the temp array tA?  As a bonus answer, since there can be multiple colors in a swatch, advice on a method to parse out all colors in a given .ase file would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance for helping me through this!

Answer (score 2):

The ASEF defines colors using RGB, assuming each color is 8 bits (called a byte). That's 24 bits of information. Unfortunately, Flash's ByteArray doesn't have a method that reads just 24 bits. So, we'll read each byte individually and combine them later.

```
var byteArray:ByteArray = _fr.data;
//Skip past the garbage that isn't the color.
for (var index:int = 0; index < numberOfBytesUntilFirstColor)
{
  byteArray.readByte();
}
var redValue:int = byteArray.readByte();
var greenValue:int = byteArray.readByte();
var blueValue:int = byteArray.readByte();
```

I'll let you calculate numberOfBytesUntilFirstColor as I'm not familiar with ASE file format.

If you want to store the value as an RGB integer, usable by Flash, do this:

```
var color:int = redValue;
color = color << 8;
color = color | greenValue;
color = color << 8;
color = color | blueValue;
```

The above code combines the individual color bytes into one 32 bit int (note, the high 8 bits are left as 0. Sometimes Flash uses the high 8 bits for the alpha, sometimes not.)